# Is there a python equivalent to the ruby inspect method?

Tags: python, inspect

In ruby you can inspect any object with the inspect method:

For example:

```
print [1,"string",:symbol,[?l, ?i, ?s, ?t]].inspect
```

will print

```
[1, "string", :symbol, ["l", "i", "s", "t"]]
```

Is there any similar facility in python which allows me to print the content of some arbitrary variable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`repr`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#repr). It returns a string containing a printable representation of an object. (similar to [`Object#inspect`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Object.html#method-i-inspect) in Ruby)

```
>>> repr([1,"string", ':symbol', ['l', 'i', 's', 't']])
"[1, 'string', ':symbol', ['l', 'i', 's', 't']]"
```

BTW, there's no symbol literal (`:symbol`) or single character string literal (`?x`) in Python; replaced them with string literals in the above example.